# NSValueTransformer for C structs in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsvaluetransformer

How do I create a `NSValueTransformer` for a C struct, such as a `CGRect` in Core Data?

Apparently `transformedValue` & `reverseTransformedValue` require and `id`. Is there a way to pass a `void*`, or a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried [`NSValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsvalue_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use NSValue to wrap C pointers.

```
[NSValue valueWithPointer:&struct]
```

Specifically for CGRect, you can use

```
[NSValue valueWithCGRect:rect]
```

which is declared in UIKit/UIGeometry.h

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work with `CATransform3D` (which can indeed be boxed by `NSValue`): `-[NSKeyedArchiver encodeValueOfObjCType:at:]: this archiver cannot encode structs`. Any tips?

Comment: I even wrote an `NSValueTransformer` subclass to convert `CATransform3D` to `NSString` and back and set that as the transformer class, but same result...